# Code Optimisation in terms of (UI) Delegate methods in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, code-reuse

I am asked to do optimise my swift code especially when it comes to UI Delegate methods.

Scenario: I have UITableView in five UIViewControllers, in each view controller I am using UITableView delegate methods due to which my code is repeating. So how can I optimise this thing?

Below is the structure of code: You can see delegate method code is repeating

```
class FirstViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var userArray = [UserModel]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        // register cell according to model (Dynamic Cells)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell01", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var productArray = [ProductModel]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        // register cell according to model (Dynamic Cells)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return productArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell01", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show _how_ your code is repeating by posting it here.

Comment: Reason to vote down?